# Laravel many to many need column from join table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

My two tables have relation in this way

```
public function orders() { 
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order'); 
}

public function products() { 
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'OrderDetails');
}
```

How can i get column for quantity? Is defined on order_product table

Comment: Can you explain your problem in detail?

Comment: Where do you save the quantity? There seems to be some really bad conception with your DB setup. Describe it more!

Answer (score 0):

Use `withPivot()`:

```
public function orders() { 
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order')->withPivot('quantity'); 
}

$orders = Product::find($id)->orders;
foreach($orders as $order) {
    // $order->pivot->quantity
}
```